# Remove Query History window from PGadmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am not sure how I activated this option in pgAdmin, but I got no idea on how to remove it.

Every time I open pgAdmin it goes through every single query which means I have to wait a couple of minutes before I can start querying again.

Does anybody know how to remove it?

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Ok I fixed it,

File -> Reset Layout.